# Problema com lista ligada de implementação dinâmica em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, pessoal, tenho duas dúvidas:

1. Por que não estou conseguindo imprimir nenhuma lista?
2. Como faço para percorrer uma lista dada, sem cabeça e sem sentinela, de trás para frente, usando esta implementação?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr {
        char letra;
        struct estr *prox;
} NO;


typedef struct{
    NO* inicio;
}LISTA;

void inicializarLista(LISTA *l){
    l->inicio = NULL;
}

void criarLista(LISTA *l, char plvr[]){
    NO* ult = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plvr); i++){
        NO* novo = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
        novo->letra = plvr[i];
        novo->prox = NULL;
        if(ult) ult->prox = novo;
        else l->inicio = novo;
        ult = novo;
    }
}

void imprimirLista(LISTA l){
    NO* p = l.inicio;
    while(p){
    printf("%d", p->letra);
    p = p->prox;
    }
}

int main() {
    LISTA l;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    char palavra = "caio";
    fgets(palavra, 3, stdin);
    criarLista(&l, palavra);
    imprimirLista(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código só tem dois probleminhas bobos.

1. Isso daqui:

   ```
       char palavra = "caio";
       fgets(palavra, 3, stdin);
   ```

   Isso daí não está certo porque `palavra` é `char`, e não `char *` ou `char []`. Acho que o que você queria era isso:

   ```
       char palavra[] = "caio";
   ```
2. Esse detalhe:

   ```
       printf("%d", p->letra);
   ```

   Acho qu você queria usar `%c` ao invés de `%d`.

Com essas alterações (e também correções na identação), o seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr {
    char letra;
    struct estr *prox;
} NO;

typedef struct {
    NO *inicio;
} LISTA;

void inicializarLista(LISTA *l) {
    l->inicio = NULL;
}

void criarLista(LISTA *l, char plvr[]) {
    NO *ult = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plvr); i++) {
        NO *novo = (NO *) malloc(sizeof(NO));
        novo->letra = plvr[i];
        novo->prox = NULL;
        if (ult) {
            ult->prox = novo;
        } else {
            l->inicio = novo;
        }
        ult = novo;
    }
}

void imprimirLista(LISTA l) {
    NO *p = l.inicio;
    while(p) {
        printf("%c", p->letra);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}

int main() {
    LISTA l;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    char palavra[] = "caio";
    //fgets(palavra, 3, stdin);
    criarLista(&l, palavra);
    imprimirLista(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Eis a saída produzida:

```
caio
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/4NUoI7)

Nessa lista, os nós têm ponteiros apenas para os próximos elementos, e não para os anteriores. Isso é uma via de mão única. Assim sendo, a melhor solução para poder percorrer de trás para frente é ter na sua estrutura `NO` o ponteiro para o elemento anterior e em `LISTA` o ponteiro para o último elemento. Sem fazer isso, para percorrer de trás para frente essa lista, até existem alguns truques que dá para fazer, mas nenhum deles é eficiente, pois em todos eles você terá que primeiramente percorrer de frente para trás e usar alguma memória auxiliar com um tamanho proporcional ao tamanho da lista. Logo, o melhor mesmo é ter o ponteiro para o elemento anterior.

Um último detalhe é que o `strlen` não é lá muito eficiente, pois ele é implementado como um `while` ou `for` que percorre a string procurando pelo terminador nulo e contando o número de iterações feitas, o que é bem ineficiente no caso de uma string que contenha um livro inteiro, por exemplo. É claro que no seu caso, como a string é pequena, o impacto no desempenho é negligível, mas é bom evitar o seu uso para criar o hábito de fazer sempre da melhor forma. Assim sendo, você poderia passar um parâmetro `tamanho` para a função `criarLista` para evitar ter que chamar a função `strlen`.